# How to extract variable names and property names from string of JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, parsing, expression, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

**Given a JavaScript expression as a string, how can I extract the names of variables used inside the expression, and going beyond that, extract the names of any properties accessed on these variables?**

These expressions are written by another author using their own personalized names like `cabbage` and `elephant.weight`.

The expression could be simple, like: `firstName`, `name.charAt(0)`, `c.radius * Math.PI`

But could also be something complex like:

```
(function(){
    var fruit = apple || banana.length;
    if (fruit > citrus.lime) {
        fruitSalad += "," + citrus.lemon;
        // ...
        return lemon.split(/[0-9]+/);
    }
    return fruitBowl.width * fruitBowl['amount'] * Math.SQRT2;
})();
```

Running the above expressions will throw reference errors unless variables like `apple` are defined. If I have a way of parsing the expression and extracting the undefined variable names, I can take note of them, and run the expression at a later time without any issues, with values for each variable.

Additionally, if I can take note of which variables have properties and the names of those properties, then I can initialize these also.

```
fruit = apple = banana = fruitSalad = "";
citrus = { lemon: "0", lime: "1" };
fruitBowl = { width: "10", amount: "30" };
// run the expression
```

### Stuff I've Tried

1. **Simply running the expression and using try/catch** to catch each reference error, parsing the exception text for the variable name. This is perilous as exception text is different in each browser. This also doesn't account for parts of the expression which aren't immediately evaluated such as in `isTrue? yesText : noText`. As accessing undefined properties of objects does not yield an error, these can't be noted.
2. **Parsing the expression into an AST** using a library such as Esprima. This is my first time using AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). I think I can access the *identifiers* used in the code but there doesn't seem to be any clear distinction between variable names and property names. As the output is quite verbose, it would be easy to let something slip. I have looked into AST walkers, but nothing stands out as being a solution.

**Note:** Assume that `eval` will not be used. Variables will always be strings or objects whose properties are strings, so knowing the type of variable is not an issue, only the names used. Names of functions used in the expressions can be ignored.

Comment: I can't see how you can do this without writing an ECMAScript parser.

Comment: _"Additionally, if I can take note of which variables have properties and the names of those properties, then I can initialize these also."_ Why can not you perform the described adjustments initially?

Comment: @guest271314 The expressions (and only the expressions) are to be written by another author, so the only way of knowing what variables and properties are needed is to analyse the expression.

Comment: why are you trying to do this?   This will be a major component of you need to parse code and guess what's needed ...  functions can easily be assigned to properties and it gets more and more complicated

Comment: Type is not an issue because all variables are assumed to be strings, or objects whose properties are strings. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: _"all variables are assumed to be strings, or objects whose properties are strings."_ ? `c.radius * Math.PI`, `citrus = { lemon: 0, lime: 1 };
fruitBowl = { width: 10, amount: 30 };`, `return fruitBowl.width * fruitBowl['amount'] * Math.SQRT2;`

Comment: Please show us your attempt at using esprima. It's the solution, so where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @guest271314 Good catch - I've amended that to more closely resemble a real world example where values passed in are only ever strings or objects of strings. Regardless, this is going down a rabbit hole which doesn't answer the core question of extracting variable/property names from JS code.

Comment: @Daniel From perspective, here, Question is not clear. Even where variable names are extracted from line of `javascript` or function, how are extracted variable names matched to values that are not provided?

Comment: Yes, you need a parser that parses the text into a tree, and yes, that gives you access to the identifiers.  But then you need analysis of the scopes, types, and uses of the identifiers, which an AST won't give you directly, further analysis is needed.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html.   Either you have to build all this machinery yourself (a lot of work), find a framework in which this work is relatively easy to do, or find a JavaScript front end in which all of this work has been done.  No, no easy way out.

Comment: @Ira Thanks for the explanation. I had a feeling I would need to further than an AST. I might need to look at another way to approach my problem so I don't need to extract variables from code, as this seems like uncharted territory.